# WSO2 EI 6.6 Code changes is not reflecting in both Eclipse and Integration Studio

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm developing a code in wso2 EI and when I'm trying to add a payload with log mediator the code is not reflected in both Eclipse and Integration Studio so what should I do to solve this issues.

Note: No error thrown while saving the code.

[image: Before:]

[image: After:]

Comment: You can't  put inside `<log>` mediator the `<payloadFactory>` mediator. What do you want to achive?

Comment: @tmoasz I'm trying to send the incoming request to an endpoint by using send mediator